# Unable to use {corr} with {dplyr::summarise} in r

Tags: r, dplyr, tidyverse

I have a data that looks like this:

[image]

I wish to calculate the correlation coefficient and the corresponding p-value between `item_response` and `subscale_sum` for every group under `subscale` (i.e. `"GP"` and `"GS"`). My code is as follows:

**`dplyr` code:**

```
df %>% 
  group_by(subscale) %>% 
  summarise(corr = cor.test(x=as.numeric(.$item_response), y=.$subscale_sum, method = 'spearman')$estimate, 
            pval = cor.test(x=as.numeric(.$item_response), y=.$subscale_sum, method = 'spearman')$p.value)
# # A tibble: 2 x 3
# subscale   corr        pval
# <chr>     <dbl>       <dbl>
# 1 GP       -0.460 0.000000719
# 2 GS       -0.460 0.000000719
```

However, I am getting the same values for both groups. Why is that so?

When I tried to do it for each group, I have different values for both groups.

**`base` code:**

```
GP <- df %>% filter(subscale == "GP")
cor.test(x=as.numeric(GP$item_response), y=GP$subscale_sum, method = 'spearman')$estimate # -0.2218538
cor.test(x=as.numeric(GP$item_response), y=GP$subscale_sum, method = 'spearman')$p.value  # 0.1103607

GS <- df %>% filter(subscale == "GS")
cor.test(x=as.numeric(GS$item_response), y=GS$subscale_sum, method = 'spearman')$estimate # -0.9012337
cor.test(x=as.numeric(GS$item_response), y=GS$subscale_sum, method = 'spearman')$p.value  # 3.691854e-20
```

Does the first code ignore my grouping?

**Data:**

```
df <- structure(list(no = c(42, 42, 43, 43, 44, 44, 45, 45, 46, 46, 
47, 47, 48, 48, 49, 49, 53, 53, 54, 54, 55, 55, 56, 56, 57, 57, 
58, 58, 59, 59, 61, 61, 62, 62, 64, 64, 65, 65, 66, 66, 67, 67, 
69, 69, 70, 70, 71, 71, 72, 72, 73, 73, 74, 74, 75, 75, 76, 76, 
77, 77, 78, 78, 79, 79, 80, 80, 81, 81, 82, 82, 84, 84, 86, 86, 
88, 88, 89, 89, 90, 90, 91, 91, 92, 92, 93, 93, 94, 94, 95, 95, 
97, 97, 98, 98, 100, 100, 101, 101, 102, 102, 103, 103, 104, 
104, 105, 105), item_response = structure(c(1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 4L, 4L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
1L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 4L, 4L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 3L, 3L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 4L, 
4L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L), .Label = c("4", "3", "2", "1"), class = c("ordered", 
"factor")), subscale = c("GP", "GS", "GP", "GS", "GP", "GS", 
"GP", "GS", "GP", "GS", "GP", "GS", "GP", "GS", "GP", "GS", "GP", 
"GS", "GP", "GS", "GP", "GS", "GP", "GS", "GP", "GS", "GP", "GS", 
"GP", "GS", "GP", "GS", "GP", "GS", "GP", "GS", "GP", "GS", "GP", 
"GS", "GP", "GS", "GP", "GS", "GP", "GS", "GP", "GS", "GP", "GS", 
"GP", "GS", "GP", "GS", "GP", "GS", "GP", "GS", "GP", "GS", "GP", 
"GS", "GP", "GS", "GP", "GS", "GP", "GS", "GP", "GS", "GP", "GS", 
"GP", "GS", "GP", "GS", "GP", "GS", "GP", "GS", "GP", "GS", "GP", 
"GS", "GP", "GS", "GP", "GS", "GP", "GS", "GP", "GS", "GP", "GS", 
"GP", "GS", "GP", "GS", "GP", "GS", "GP", "GS", "GP", "GS", "GP", 
"GS"), subscale_sum = c(23, 24, 15, 24, 25, 24, 15, 24, 22, 24, 
15, 24, 19, 24, 14, 24, 23, 24, 16, 24, 14, 24, 18, 24, 25, 24, 
23, 24, 22, 24, 20, 24, 15, 24, 28, 24, 23, 24, 13, 24, 20, 20, 
25, 24, 28, 24, 19, 24, 19, 24, 21, 24, 19, 24, 21, 24, 21, 16, 
24, 0, 8, 24, 24, 24, 10, 18, 8, 24, 24, 24, 19, 18, 5, 24, 14, 
6, 24, 24, 9, 24, 8, 18, 5, 24, 19, 24, 16, 24, 17, 24, 18, 24, 
18, 12, 16, 18, 21, 24, 10, 24, 10, 6, 16, 24, 16, 18)), row.names = c(NA, 
-106L), class = c("tbl_df", "tbl", "data.frame"))
```

Comment: Instead of `as.numeric(.$item_response)` in your summarise function, use `as.numeric(item_response)`.

Comment: Same for subscale_sum

Comment: Oh it make sense now, thanks @AdamQuek

Answer (score 0):

This may works

```
df %>% 
  group_by(subscale) %>%
  mutate(item_response = as.numeric(item_response)) %>%
  summarize(coef = cor.test(item_response, subscale_sum)$estimate,
            pval = cor.test(item_response, subscale_sum)$p.value)

  subscale   coef     pval
  <chr>     <dbl>    <dbl>
1 GP       -0.151 2.82e- 1
2 GS       -0.961 3.12e-30
```

Answer (score 0):

Instead of applying the `cor.test` multiple, do it once, extract the ones that are needed from the `list`

```
library(dplyr)
library(tidyr)
df %>%
  group_by(subscale) %>% 
  mutate(item_response = as.numeric(item_response)) %>% 
  summarise(out = as_tibble(cor.test(item_response, 
         subscale_sum)[c("estimate", "p.value")])) %>% 
  unnest(out)
# A tibble: 2 × 3
  subscale estimate  p.value
  <chr>       <dbl>    <dbl>
1 GP         -0.151 2.82e- 1
2 GS         -0.961 3.12e-30
```

---

or use `broom::tidy` to convert the `list` directly to a tibble, `select` the elements and `unnest` the column

```
library(dplyr)
library(tidyr)
df %>% 
  group_by(subscale) %>%
  mutate(item_response = as.numeric(item_response)) %>% 
  summarise(out = broom::tidy(cor.test(item_response, subscale_sum)) %>% 
          select(coef = estimate, pval = p.value)) %>% 
  unnest(out)
# A tibble: 2 × 3
  subscale   coef     pval
  <chr>     <dbl>    <dbl>
1 GP       -0.151 2.82e- 1
2 GS       -0.961 3.12e-30
```

Comment: I wanted to use the `broom::tidy` but I am not getting the dataframe that you got. Mine is  #A tibble: 4 x 2
  subscale       out
  <chr>        <dbl>
1 GP       -1.51e- 1
2 GP       -9.61e- 1
3 GS        2.82e- 1
4 GS        3.12e-30

Comment: @HNSKD Can you specify `dplyr::mutate` and `dplyr::summarise` in case there is masking